# How can I locally address an <img> without xampp prepending localhost to the image address

Tags: xampp

I'm using Xampp locally to run php within a directory structure like this:

```
D:/LaunchBox/mySoftware/xampp-project/index.php
```

I'm trying to display an image with HTML that resides here:

```
D:/LaunchBox/Images/Platforms/myImage.png
```

So my tag is:

```
<img src="D:/LaunchBox/Images/Platforms/myImage.png">
```

The image isn't being displayed. If I hover over the image address when using "inspect" within Chrome I see the following address:

```
http://localhost/D:/LaunchBox/Images/Platforms/myImage.png
```

I've tried just using ../Images/etc but to no avail.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I'm stuck? Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I've cracked it. Just in case someone else has a similar issue this is what I did. I set up Virtual Hosts in Xampp [following the instructions here](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configure-virtual-host-on-windows-10-for-wordpress/)

Then I addressed my software with the following inside xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "D:\LaunchBox"
ServerName arcade-project.com
<Directory "D:\LaunchBox">
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can now access my project with the URL arcade-project.com

And, from within my code, I can display images by just using a relative URL such as:

```
./Images/Platforms/myImage.png
```